# Extracting DN(distinguished name) in ldap

Tags: python, ldap, python-ldap

I am writing a piece of code that uses authentication from ldap server. Currently my code only lets the user DN and the pwd to be presented for login.

```
Username: CN=mynane,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com
Pwd : XXXX
```

Now what is want to do is allow the username in the format

```
Username: myname@example.com
Pwd: xxxx
```

I can bind to the server using the credentials in the format "myname@example.com", but my code needs the group of the 'myname' as well for authentication. For that I need to find out the DN from "myname@example.com" so that I can extract the group 'myname' belongs to.

**So my question is how can I find out the DN from format "myname@example.com"**

How is it done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query dn by email address, you might try the following codes.

```
ldap = "SELECT distinguishedName From 'LDAP://DC=example,DC=com' WHERE mail = '{}'"
mail = 'myname@example.com'

import win32com.client
c = win32com.client.Dispatch('ADODB.Connection')
c.Open('Provider=ADsDSOObject')
rs,rc = c.Execute(ldap.format(mail))
while not rs.EOF:
    for e in rs.fields:
        print('{}: {}'.format(e.Name, e.Value))
    rs.MoveNext()
```

Comment: I am not sure, but i think what the above code is doing is extracting the DN attribute of the entry whose mail is the mail given during authentication. Has the "myname@example.com" anything to do with the e-mail of the user "myname".

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you said. myname@example.com isn't the user's email, is it? Or maybe a user hasn't email enabled but he can use "myname@example.com" to be authenticated?

Comment: No the myname@example.com isnt the users email. Sorry, I got confused at first :). I am using python-ldap, for binding to server and querying the database. Doesnt python-ldap allow this? I mean the above type of work.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to fetch the user whose 'userPrincipalName'='myname@example.com' or 'samAccountName'='myname'

Answer (score 0):

You have to do two things:

1. Find the right subtree for the DNS domain example.com (usually from the Configuration subtree), if you only have one domain, its easier, simply ignore the part after the @.
2. Look inside that subtree for the sAMAccountName=myname, as it is unique inside the domain.

Those names often look like UPNs but aren't. In fact they are usually just the sAMAccountName attached to the DNS domain name.